# I want to get 2 tables from mysql and check 2 object but I couldn't count it how can I do could you help for me?

Tags: laravel-5

public function matchOrNot()
{
$belediyeprofils = DB::table('belediye_profil')->join('envanter_genel', 'envanter_genel.belediye_id', '=', 'belediye_profil.id')->where('envanter_genel.status', 8)->get();
// $envantergenels = DB::table('envanter_genel')->join('belediye_profil', 'envanter_genel.belediye_id', '=', 'belediye_profil.id')->get();

```
    $i=0;

    
    foreach ($belediyeprofils as $belediyeprofil) 
    if($i<100)
    {
    {
       
            $q = $belediyeprofil->name;
            $w = $belediyeprofil->ilce;
            $s = $belediyeprofil->id; 
            
    }
    if(strpos($q, $w)!== false)
    {
            return $s ; //Matched
    }
            else
    {
            $returnData = //notMatched
            [
                
                    'Sayaç' => $i,
                    'Id' => $s,
                    'Belediye' => $q,
                    'İlçe' => $w,
                    
                  
            ];  
            return response()->json($returnData, 200);;
    }           
    }
    
            $i++;
            $s++;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

public function matchOrNot()
{
$belediyeprofils = DB::table('belediye_profil')->join('envanter_genel', 'envanter_genel.belediye_id', '=', 'belediye_profil.id')->where('envanter_genel.status', 8)->get();
// $envantergenels = DB::table('envanter_genel')->join('belediye_profil', 'envanter_genel.belediye_id', '=', 'belediye_profil.id')->get();
// $totalIslem = EnvanterGenel::where('envanter_id', $id)->where('durum', 8)->count();

```
    $i=0;
  
    foreach ($belediyeprofils as $belediyeprofil) 
    {
     if($i <4)
        
     {      
                       
            if(strpos($belediyeprofil->name, $belediyeprofil->ilce)!== true)
            
            {
                  
              
                $is = $belediyeprofil->id;
                $belediye = $belediyeprofil->name;
                $ilce = $belediyeprofil->ilce; 
                $returnData[$i] = [
                  
                    'id' => $is,
                    'belediye' => $belediye,
                    'ilce' => $ilce,
                    
                   
                  
                ];
                return response()->json($returnData[$i], 200);
                
               
               
            }  
            
        }  $i++;
      
        
        
       
}
 
    
     
}
```

Comment: Can anyone help me about $is++

Comment: I mean Id and i not count for now. I couldn't count it